# Why is my recyclerview duplicating the first item only on list?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have this layout where I get the number of orders and display it on my recyclerview. The problem is I have 2 items on my list, which is 1234 and 1235. All data from 1234 are being displayed but it loops twice since there are 2 items.

> **Here is the code for the Adapter.**

```
public class ReportDeliveredJobOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportDeliveredJobOrderAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<JobOrderItem> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Callback.HistoryItemListener callback;

    ReportDeliveredJobOrderAdapter(Context context) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    void updateHistoryAdapter(List<JobOrderItem> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setCallback(Callback.HistoryItemListener callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_report_delivered_job_order, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(viewItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Object object = objects.get(position);
        holder.bindJobOrder(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.lblJobOrderID)
        TextView lblJobOrderID;
         @BindView(R.id.layoutDeliveredJO)
        ConstraintLayout layoutDeliveredJO;
        private JobOrderItem jobOrderItem;
        final List<JobOrderItem> jobOrderItems = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                int position = getLayoutPosition();
                if (callback != null && position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (jobOrderItem.consignment_status != null) {
                        if (Preferences.getString(Prefkey.session_consignment_type).equals("runner-profiles") && jobOrderItem.consignment_status.equals("PrimaryRunner")) {
                            callback.onClickItem(jobOrderItem);
                        } else if (jobOrderItem.consignment_status.equals("withShopper")) {
                            Entity primary_shopper_profile = getPrimaryShopperEntity(jobOrderItem);
                            if (primary_shopper_profile != null) {
                                AppUtil.displayToast(context, context.getString(R.string.consignment_coordinate_shopper));
                            }
                        } else {
                            AppUtil.displayToast(context, context.getString(R.string.consignment_history_coordinate));
                        }
                    } else {
                        AppUtil.displayToast(context, context.getString(R.string.consignment_history_coordinate));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        void bindJobOrder(Object object) {
            this.jobOrderItem = (JobOrderItem) object;

            for (Entity job_order : jobOrderItem.job_orders) {
                lblJobOrderID.setText(String.format("JO# %s", job_order.id));
            }
        }

    }
```

> ```
> I am calling the jobOrderItems on DeliveredCheckoutAdapter. This is the code.
> ```

void bindCheckout(Object object) {
            this.jobOrderItem = (JobOrderItem) object;

```
        grand_total_amount = 0;
        total_job_order_purchased_amount = 0;
        total_job_order_delivery_fee = 0;
        total_job_order_shopping_fee = 0;
        total_job_order_discount = 0;
        total_privilege_fee = 0;
        total_credits = 0;
        total_recalled = 0;
        total_campaign_discount = 0;

        jobOrderItems.clear();

        final Date completed_at = parseServerDate(jobOrderItem.job_order.attributes.completed_at);

        for (Entity job_order : jobOrderItem.job_orders) {
            total_job_order_purchased_amount += job_order.attributes.purchased_deliverables_amount_in_cents;
            total_job_order_delivery_fee += job_order.attributes.delivery_fee_in_cents;
            total_privilege_fee += job_order.attributes.non_membership_fee_in_cents;
            total_job_order_shopping_fee += job_order.attributes.shopping_fee_in_cents;
            total_credits += job_order.attributes.credit_amount_of_cents;
            total_recalled += job_order.attributes.recalled_deliverables_amount_in_cents;
        }

        for (JobOrderItem jobOrderItem : jobOrderItem.jobOrderItemList) {
            if (!jobOrderItem.job_order.attributes.status.equals("cancelled")) {
                if (jobOrderItem.job_order.relationships.completed_by_user.data.id.equals(Preferences.getString(Prefkey.session_user_id))) {


                    for (Entity campaigndiscount : jobOrderItem.campaigndiscounts) {
                        if (!jobOrderItem.job_order.attributes.status.equals("cancelled")) {
                            total_campaign_discount += campaigndiscount.attributes.discount_in_cents;
                        }
                    }


                    for (Entity discount : jobOrderItem.discounts) {
                        long job_order_discount;

                        if (discount.relationships.job_order.data.id.equals(jobOrderItem.job_order.id)) {
                            long purchase_amount = jobOrderItem.job_order.attributes.purchased_deliverables_amount_in_cents;
                            if (discount.attributes.sum_in_cents_off <= 0) {
                                job_order_discount = Math.round(purchase_amount * discount.attributes.percent_off);
                            } else {
                                job_order_discount = discount.attributes.sum_in_cents_off;
                            }
                            jobOrderItem.discount = purchase_amount;
                            total_job_order_discount += job_order_discount;
                        }
                    }

                    if (jobOrderItem.consignments.size() > 0) {
                        for (Entity consignment : jobOrderItem.consignments) {
                            Entity user = AppUtil.getEntity(consignment.relationships.user.data.id, jobOrderItem.users);

                            if (user.relationships.profile.data.type.equals("shopper-profiles")) {
                                if (consignment.attributes.primary) {
                                    jobOrderItem.consignment_status = "withShopper";
                                }

                            } else if (user.relationships.profile.data.type.equals("runner-profiles")) {
                                if (consignment.attributes.primary) {
                                    if (jobOrderItem.consignment_status == null || !jobOrderItem.consignment_status.equals("withShopper")) {
                                        if (consignment.relationships.user.data.id.equals(Preferences.getString(Prefkey.session_user_id))) {
                                            jobOrderItem.consignment_status = "PrimaryRunner";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    if (jobOrderItem.consignments.size() > 0) {
                        for (Entity consignment : jobOrderItem.consignments) {
                            Entity user = AppUtil.getEntity(consignment.relationships.user.data.id, jobOrderItem.users);
                            if (user.relationships.profile.data.type.equals("shopper-profiles")) {
                                if (consignment.attributes.primary) {
                                    jobOrderItem.consignment_status = "withShopper";
                                }

                            } else if (user.relationships.profile.data.type.equals("runner-profiles")) {
                                if (consignment.attributes.primary) {
                                    if (jobOrderItem.consignment_status == null || !jobOrderItem.consignment_status.equals("withShopper")) {
                                        if (consignment.relationships.user.data.id.equals(Preferences.getString(Prefkey.session_user_id))) {
                                            jobOrderItem.consignment_status = "PrimaryRunner";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            jobOrderItems.add(jobOrderItem);

        }
        reportDeliveredJobOrderAdapter.updateHistoryAdapter(jobOrderItems);

    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code where you're creating the `List<JobOrderItem>` that you give to the `Adapter`.

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry, List<JobOrderItem> is not included. That was an unused variable.

Comment: Your `Adapter` is pulling its data items from the `private List<JobOrderItem> objects`. The only place you're setting that – other than the initialization – is in `updateHistoryAdapter(List<JobOrderItem> objects)`. Please show us the code that creates the list that you call that method with.

Comment: @MikeM. I edited my question. I call it on DeliveredCheckoutAdapter.

Comment: Well, your `ReportDeliveredJobOrderAdapter` code looks fine, so that would seem to indicate that the list that you're giving it has the same item in it multiple times. I'm too tired to follow all of that code you just added, but my first suggestion would be to debug to check the items in the `jobOrderItems` list when you call `reportDeliveredJobOrderAdapter.updateHistoryAdapter(jobOrderItems)`.